# Running windows app tests in parallel

Tags: c#, tfs, automation, parallel-testing, leanft

The problem I am facing is a unique one.. I have set up a testing suite for a windows app using LeanFT and NUnit. At this point, I have around 100 stable UI tests that I have automatically running nightly on a VM I have configured.

The problem is, I do not think there is an out of the box solution for running tests in parallel across multiple machines. When the tests are kicked off of TFS, they run on a single machine. What I want is for tests to be passed out 1 at a time to any available machine.

I know I can "fake" this in a sense by having two different build definitions run at the same time with a different set of tests, but this is not what I want to do. I want it to work like an actual grid and pass out tests like the selenium grid does. Has anyone had any luck with something like this by not faking it?

Note: we do not use Jenkins, we do everything out of TFS.

Comment: Isn't TFS build process is WFF-based project that runs on template provided by MS? Use it as base of your own WF and try run actions async. Generally speaking, TFS build is a free tool. If it was good, there wouldn't be proliferation or other tools fro this purpose.  also, you can use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/ ?

Team Foundation Server does have 'build agents' like Jenkins does. While I'm not familiar with this, it appears to be close to what you are looking for.